# How motion capture system works?

Tags: computer-vision, computer-games

Can you explain in step-by-step basis of how motion capture system work? Especially the part, that enables the 3D models to mimic the movement of the actor.

Comment: This sounds a bit broad to me.  What research have you done?  What have you found so far?  Sharing your research helps everyone -- see http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Look up a guide on Kinect programming.  They go into details about how it all works.